# Frequency Analysis Character Distribution Data

Tags: data-request, language

Is there a location I can download character distributions for [frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) used in decryption attempt validation? I am specifically interested in [ASCII value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) [32, 126] frequency distribution for plain English language text. This would imply case-sensitivity and include punctuation. I'm not concerned with data formats.

Comment: You might have to take some larger body (the standard term is 'corpus', such as [BYU's Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) and reduce it yourself.  Most focus on words & phrases, so might not have all of the punctuation and such that you're asking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Second try: [Google Ngram Viewer](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html) contains raw counts of 1-, 2-, ...-grams of text, retrieved from its book scanning endeavor. The section 1-grams contains counts of the occurence of lettres, numbers and even punctuation. They are provided as tab-separated value files, so the frequencies should be derivable with modest scripting efforts.

Found via Wikipedia article [Text corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus).

Answer (score 1):

What about the (frequency analysis) article's first link to [Letter frequency (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_letters_in_the_English_language)? It lists letter distribution for English and other languages, all properly sourced:

```
Letter   Relfreq
----------------
e        12.702%    
t         9.056%    
a         8.167%    
o         7.507%    
i         6.966%    
n         6.749%    
s         6.327%    
...
```

Comment: I was looking for all ASCII values [0,127] or at least printable ASCII values [32,126].

Comment: @awashburn Why can't you manually convert them?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO these table only deal with a case-insensitive alphabet, while the question asks for ASCII frequencies, so at least lower-/uppercase letters, numbers and punctuation should be included. This is what I tried to address in my second answer.